# Azure functions with durable functions on .net framework

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I've got an Azure function which I have requirements to stay on .net framework.
I also want to use durable functions.

New project add the latest v1 SDK and latest DurableTask.Core / Extensions.Durable Task.

Compile and I get errors. Looks like a conflict in `HttpRequestMessageExtensions` in same name space in both `system.web.http` and `microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.webapicompatshim` Looks like it was introduced in https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask/1.8.5

Error : 
`error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateResponse<T>(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage, System.Net.HttpStatusCode, T)' and 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateResponse<T>(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage, System.Net.HttpStatusCode, T)'`

Project file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v1</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.DurableTask.Core" Version="2.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="2.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.36" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

FunctionClass 
Note: This is based on new template, not using durable functions here but require it.

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DurableTask.Core;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public static class Function1
    {

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            // parse query parameter
            string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
                .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
                .Value;

            if (name == null)
            {
                // Get request body
                dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
                name = data?.name;
            }

            return name == null
                ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body")
                : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + name);
        }
    }
}
```

Has anyone else had this and how to resolve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gone with `return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);`